# Nameservers / DNS questions

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, nameserver

I've got one VPS and I want to get one more.

Currently both of my nameservers (ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com) are set to the IP of my VPS.
What if I want to get one more, what should I do with the nameservers? Set the 2nd one to the IP of the 2nd VPS? What if I get more VPS, doubt I can have up to 6-7 nameservers. How should I do it? I currently use CentOS Web Panel, and I set the nameservers records to ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com, and it is fine, but with more VPS?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Are you running a name server in your VPS, and if so, why only 1?

Comment: It doesn't really matter what you do at this point.  You should never have only one name server.  Two names pointing at one IP is still one nameserver.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and easiest option.

Migrate your DNS to Cloudflare. It will be 1000x more reliable than trying to run your own BIND/DNS servers.

Comment: Second that. Unless you need a local DNS (i.e. Active Directory) this is the best solution. Period.

Comment: I already have it on Cloudflare and I have Unproxied NS1 and NS2 pointing to VPS1 server, but if I have multiple servers what should I do? Where should I point them?

Comment: What sort of records is your NS1.domain.com ? Is it an A record or an NS record?

Comment: It's an A record. https://prnt.sc/so1v1r

Comment: If they are just A records and nothing actually uses them for anything. Then you can safely delete them. They aren't your nameservers (Providing your domain is using Cloudflare and that is backed up by requests showing etc in the CF portal)

Comment: I'm using them, they are set in CentOS web panel as nameservers and they do work. But I'm asking what should the nameservers be if I have more servers, for example 5 servers, do they have to be each server IP? So ns1 is VPS1 IP, ns2 is VPS2 IP, vps3 is vps3 ip and so on. How can I host my nameservers on cloudflare?

Comment: You don't seem to be understanding me. If you aren't running a DNS server such as BIND on your VPS's then they aren't actual nameservers. What are your nameservers actually set as? Do an SOA lookup. If NS1.yourdomain isn't in there then they aren't actually your nameservers.

An A record is simply a way to translate a DNS name into an IP address

Comment: Ok, I've created a private nameserver in NameSilo's Domain Manager, now what should I do? Also I have maximum 8 nameservers, if I have 10 VPS servers where should I point the VPS IP?

Comment: And I ran a lookup for a domain hosted there and working, my nameservers are there. But I'm asking if I have more VPS, what should I do with the nameservers? Or what IP should I put for the nameserver. Currently I have for both nameservers (ns1 and ns2) the IP for VPS1. But if I get more VPS, what should I do with the nameservers?
ns1.example.com -> pointing to VPS1 IP
ns2.example.com -> pointing to VPS2 IP
ns3.example.com -> pointing to VPS3 IP
and so on?